# Java very slow method

Tags: java

I noticed that one of my methods is being very slow, with profiling I noticed it took up like 95% of the total execution time.

The class:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

/**
 *
 * @author Frank
 */
public abstract class CustomRectangle {
    protected final BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    protected final int width;
    protected final int height;
    protected final int xOffset;
    protected final int yOffset;
    protected final int borderSize;
    protected final boolean defaultOrientation;

    protected Color color;

    public CustomRectangle(final BufferedImage bufferedImage, final int width, final int height, final int xOffset, final int yOffset, final int borderSize, final boolean defaultOrientation) {
        this.bufferedImage = bufferedImage;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        if (defaultOrientation) {
            this.xOffset = xOffset;
            this.yOffset = yOffset;
        }
        else {
            this.xOffset = bufferedImage.getWidth() - 1 - xOffset;
            this.yOffset = bufferedImage.getHeight() - 1 - yOffset;
        }
        this.borderSize = borderSize;
        this.defaultOrientation = defaultOrientation;
    }

    abstract public void inBorder(final int dx, final int dy);

    abstract public void outBorder(final int dx, final int dy);

    public void draw() {
        if (defaultOrientation) {
            drawDefaultOrientation();
        }
        else {
            drawOppositeOrientation();
        }
    }

    private void drawDefaultOrientation() {
        int[] pixelArray = ((DataBufferInt)bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int dx = Math.min(x, width - 1 - x);
                int dy = Math.min(y, height - 1 - y);
                if (dx < borderSize || dy < borderSize) {
                    inBorder(dx, dy);
                }
                else {
                    outBorder(dx, dy);
                }
                pixelArray[(xOffset + x) + ((yOffset + y) * bufferedImage.getWidth())] = color.getRGB();
            }
        }
    }    

    private void drawOppositeOrientation() {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int dx = Math.min(x, width - 1 - x);
                int dy = Math.min(y, height - 1 - y);
                if (dx < borderSize || dy < borderSize) {
                    inBorder(dx, dy);
                }
                else {
                    outBorder(dx, dy);
                }
                bufferedImage.setRGB(xOffset - x, yOffset - y, color.getRGB());              
            }
        }
    }  

    public void setColor(final Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

The slow method is the drawDefaultOrientation() method.
The scary part however is that even if I leave out all image-modifying code, then it is still slow.

The callee code:

```
    new CustomRectangle(bufferedImage, 440, 180, 30, 490, 10, defaultOrientation) {
        @Override
        public void inBorder(final int dx, final int dy) {
            setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 255 - (int)Math.round(0.5 * Math.min(dx, dy))));
        }

        @Override
        public void outBorder(final int dx, final int dy) {
            setColor(new Color(red, green, blue, 128 - (int)Math.round(0.5 * Math.min(dx, dy))));
        }
    }.draw();
```

There must be something going on as in any way this code should not take this long, even if it loops over x and y coordinates.

Some thought I had was that it could have to do with the Anonymous inner class + Override...

But hopefully someone with more knowledge can answer the question.

Comment: Taking 95% of the total execution time does not mean that the method is slow. It means that your program spends most of its time in that method. `main()` takes 100% of the total execution time in a single-threaded program.

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrongfully. I more mean that it does use 95% of execution, but it does not do anything useful in that time basically.

Comment: What do `inborder` and `outborder` do? Also, it looks like you can move the call to `color.getRGB()` outside the loop.

Comment: Could you come up with a self-contained benchmark that we can experiment with?

Comment: Were you able to profile which call inside `drawDefaultOrientation` is slow?

Comment: Try changing this: `int[] pixelArray = ((DataBufferInt)bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` into `int[] pixelArray = makeArray(bufferedImage);` and `private static int[] makeArray(BufferedImage bufImage) { ((DataBufferInt)bufImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); }` and seeing what the profiler says

Comment: Which profiler are you using?

You could download something like YourKit, for example, where you can take a snapshot and look for code "hot-spots". This highlights areas where most time is spent and breaks down the time per method call. I suggest YourKit as I'm most familiar with it and it does this very well but most profilers will do the same.

You'd increment the generation, run your method where time is known to be lost, take a snapshot and alalyse for hotspots. You could then see the iteration count and time spent and use that to dissect the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Currently I have found that the issue is quite "simple", basically it does millions of calls to the inBorder() and outBorder() methods. Nothing in my code is exceptionally slow, it is just the fact that it is called millions of times. I need to rethink some of my code simply to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: If `red`, `green`, `blue` don't change, then stop using an anonymous class, and in your implemented subclass do: (note, this might not work, but the basic idea should, if you can avoid constantly calling `new Color` by caching all the colors you might need)

```
private final Color[] colors;

public ImplementedCustomRectangle(...) {
    super(...); // ... is not real code, I just don't want to copy/paste

    colors = new Color[256];
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        colors[i] = new Color(red, green, blue, i);
    }
}

@Override
public void inBorder(final int dx, final int dy) {
    int value = 255 - (int)Math.round(0.5 * Math.min(dx, dy));
    setColor(colors[value]);
}

@Override
public void outBorder(final int dx, final int dy) {
    int value = 128 - (int)Math.round(0.5 * Math.min(dx, dy);
    setColor(colors[value]);
}
```